# Java Short constant pool versus short primitives

Tags: java, reference, primitive, pool

My solution requires many constant variables, so in further development i could simply create new primitives or reference existing data, instead of creating new one, that excludes possible mistakes made in future development process.

I've read that java pools constant variables, when new data is created it compares with the pool, if such object exists it returns reference to existing one instead of creating new one.

While pooling might sound best approach, in my case, i need many *short* variables, which allocates 2 bytes (for a primitive) each. But if I'd create *Short* i would loose 2 byte, because reference would take 4 bytes.

Would it make sense to still use primitives even considering that Short uses pooling. Plus, unboxing from Short to short also takes some resources (which are almost close to zero, but still). Note that short will have to converted to primitive 3 byte array time to time, so another + for primitive.

```
public static final short USER = 10;
```

instead of

```
public static final Short USER = 10;
```

Comment: A short uses 2 bytes, not 3.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, i meant 2, edited.

Comment: What happened when you did some profiling to compare the two approaches you mentioned?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - The first approach ought to be faster. It is a *compile time constant*

Comment: I tested it with hundreds of millions of entries, couple times, there wasn't any 'huge' difference, but i i believe primitives gave slightly better results. But that might be by chance. I dont really know how it manages the pooling, i dont know if there are any gains or downs to the pooling under heavier loads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important thing here is primitives are way way cheaper than object wrappers, in both time and memory complexities.

The pooling feature only becomes relevant if you have to use these primitives in contexts where Object references have to be used (i.e. they have to be wrapped/"boxed" into their object wrappers, google auto-boxing). If you can use them as primitive numbers all the time then it is the most efficient way.

Details:

The Java language treats primitives types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, double) differently from all other types (which are reference types). The primitives can directly exist on the stack and can be directly manipulated by JVM instructions (there're sets of instructions for each of the primitives). Numerical constants are often directly embeded into JVM instructions, which means no additional memory read is needed to execute these instructions. This structure maps more or less directly to native code on all hardware.

The reference types on the other hand cannot exist on the stack and must be allocated on the heap (this is a Java language design choice). This means each time you use them, instructions has to be added to find the instance, read meta data, invoke a method or get a field before any real operation on the data can be performed.

For example, say you have the function

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

The body of the function (apart from calling convention) will be simply `iadd`, which translates to 1 instruction on most CPUs.

If you change the `int`s into `Integers`s, the byte code becomes:

```
   0: aload_1
   1: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   4: aload_2
   5: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   8: iadd
   9: invokestatic  #22                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

which translates to multiple internal function calls and thousands of native instructions.

Random notes:

IIRC, the Java language spec did not define how many bytes will be used to store `short`, `boolean`, etc. The JVM implementation may use more bytes so it aligns everything with the word length of the CPU. It is not unusual to see a boolean stored as a byte or a 32-bit int purely for efficiency purposes. It did say however, that the result of operations on types shorter than `int` all comes out as `int`.

All of these means `short` doesn't really give you any memory savings unless you have very large `short` arrays (which has to be packed without gap in memory).

And if you really, really want to use a pool of `Short`s (the wrapper), the most efficient implementation is an array of size 65536. Here you exchange 4k/8k of memory for very efficient lookups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sadly i cant upvote it, yet.

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure why you need `Short`. Anyways, as a thumb rule always remember that *primitives are always faster and cheaper when compared to their wrappers*. They aren't objects so many JIT optimizations can result in really fast code. Also, Wrappers don't contain cache for all possible values - for example `Integer` has (by default) a cache for -128 to 127. You can extend it, but thats not the point.

If you need to push shorts into a collection, then probably using a cache makes sense (Wrappers already have cache between -128 to 127). Yet, if you want to push millions of numbers, then not using a cache makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By 'not quite sure why you need Short' you mean it's pretty much useless comparing to primitive in any scenario or you could give example where it might be actual better to use Short. 
Except the scenario where java.util collection accept wrappers only.

Comment: @Scavs :-) I am not saying `Short` is *useless*. I am saying that if your work can be done by only shorts, then using primitives is always better. So, again, do you have a specific reason to use `Short` in your code?

Comment: I dont have any requirements for the Short, in fact i want to go with short personally. Must the the term pooling hyped me up (; .
That's why i had doubts.

Comment: @Scavs - Yes, I would also prefer *short* over *Short*.